# Minimize cudaDeviceSynchronize launch overhead

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, tegra

I'm currently doing a project with CUDA where a pipeline is refreshed with 200-10000 new events every 1ms. Each time, I want to call one(/two) kernels which compute a small list of outputs; then fed those outputs to the next element of the pipeline.

The theoretical flow is:

1. receive data in an `std::vector`
2. `cudaMemcpy` the vector to GPU
3. processing
4. generate small list of outputs
5. `cudaMemcpy` to the output `std::vector`

But when I'm calling `cudaDeviceSynchronize` on a 1block/1thread empty kernel with no processing, it already takes in average 0.7 to 1.4ms, which is already higher than my 1ms timeframe.

I could eventually change the timeframe of the pipeline in order to receive events every 5ms, but with 5x more each times. It wouldn't be ideal though.

What would be the best way to minimize the overhead of `cudaDeviceSynchronize`? Could streams be helpful in this situation? Or another solution to efficiently run the pipeline.

*(Jetson TK1, compute capabilities 3.2)*

Here's a nvprof log of the applications:

```
==8285== NVPROF is profiling process 8285, command: python player.py test.rec
==8285== Profiling application: python player.py test.rec
==8285== Profiling result:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 94.92%  47.697ms      5005  9.5290us  1.7500us  13.083us  reset_timesurface(__int64, __int64*, __int64*, __int64*, __int64*, float*, float*, bool*, bool*, Event*)
  5.08%  2.5538ms         8  319.23us  99.750us  413.42us  [CUDA memset]

==8285== API calls:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 75.00%  5.03966s      5005  1.0069ms  25.083us  11.143ms  cudaDeviceSynchronize
 17.44%  1.17181s      5005  234.13us  83.750us  3.1391ms  cudaLaunch
  4.71%  316.62ms         9  35.180ms  23.083us  314.99ms  cudaMalloc
  2.30%  154.31ms     50050  3.0830us  1.0000us  2.6866ms  cudaSetupArgument
  0.52%  34.857ms      5005  6.9640us  2.5000us  464.67us  cudaConfigureCall
  0.02%  1.2048ms         8  150.60us  71.917us  183.33us  cudaMemset
  0.01%  643.25us        83  7.7490us  1.3330us  287.42us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
  0.00%  12.916us         2  6.4580us  2.0000us  10.916us  cuDeviceGetCount
  0.00%  5.3330us         1  5.3330us  5.3330us  5.3330us  cuDeviceTotalMem
  0.00%  4.0830us         1  4.0830us  4.0830us  4.0830us  cuDeviceGetName
  0.00%  3.4160us         2  1.7080us  1.5830us  1.8330us  cuDeviceGet
```

A small reconstitution of the program *(nvprof log at the end)* - for some reason, the average of `cudaDeviceSynchronize` is 4 times lower, but it's still really high for an empty 1-thread kernel:

```
/* Compile with `nvcc test.cu -I.`
 * with -I pointing to "helper_cuda.h" and "helper_string.h" from CUDA samples
 **/
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <helper_cuda.h>

#define MAX_INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE 131072

typedef struct {
    unsigned short x;
    unsigned short y;
    short a;
    long long b;
} Event;

long long *d_a_[2], *d_b_[2];
float *d_as_, *d_bs_;
bool *d_some_bool_[2];
Event *d_data_;
int width_ = 320;
int height_ = 240;

__global__ void reset_timesurface(long long ts,
        long long *d_a_0, long long *d_a_1,
        long long *d_b_0, long long *d_b_1,
        float *d_as, float *d_bs,
        bool *d_some_bool_0, bool *d_some_bool_1, Event *d_data) {
    // nothing here
}
void reset_errors(long long ts) {
    static const int n  = 1024;
    static const dim3 grid_size(width_ * height_ / n
            + (width_ * height_ % n != 0), 1, 1);
    static const dim3 block_dim(n, 1, 1);

    reset_timesurface<<<1, 1>>>(ts, d_a_[0], d_a_[1],
            d_b_[0], d_b_[1],
            d_as_, d_bs_,
            d_some_bool_[0], d_some_bool_[1], d_data_);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    //  static long long *h_holder = (long long*)malloc(sizeof(long long) * 2000);
    //  cudaMemcpy(h_holder, d_a_[0], 0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
}

int main(void) {
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&(d_a_[0]), sizeof(long long)*width_*height_*2));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemset(d_a_[0], 0, sizeof(long long)*width_*height_*2));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&(d_a_[1]), sizeof(long long)*width_*height_*2));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemset(d_a_[1], 0, sizeof(long long)*width_*height_*2));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&(d_b_[0]), sizeof(long long)*width_*height_*2));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemset(d_b_[0], 0, sizeof(long long)*width_*height_*2));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&(d_b_[1]), sizeof(long long)*width_*height_*2));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemset(d_b_[1], 0, sizeof(long long)*width_*height_*2));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&d_as_, sizeof(float)*width_*height_*2));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemset(d_as_, 0, sizeof(float)*width_*height_*2));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&d_bs_, sizeof(float)*width_*height_*2));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemset(d_bs_, 0, sizeof(float)*width_*height_*2));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&(d_some_bool_[0]), sizeof(bool)*width_*height_*2));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemset(d_some_bool_[0], 0, sizeof(bool)*width_*height_*2));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&(d_some_bool_[1]), sizeof(bool)*width_*height_*2));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemset(d_some_bool_[1], 0, sizeof(bool)*width_*height_*2));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&d_data_, sizeof(Event)*MAX_INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE));

    for (int i = 0; i < 5005; ++i)
        reset_errors(16487L);

    cudaFree(d_a_[0]);
    cudaFree(d_a_[1]);
    cudaFree(d_b_[0]);
    cudaFree(d_b_[1]);
    cudaFree(d_as_);
    cudaFree(d_bs_);
    cudaFree(d_some_bool_[0]);
    cudaFree(d_some_bool_[1]);
    cudaFree(d_data_);
    cudaDeviceReset();
}

/* nvprof ./a.out
==9258== NVPROF is profiling process 9258, command: ./a.out
==9258== Profiling application: ./a.out
==9258== Profiling result:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 92.64%  48.161ms      5005  9.6220us  6.4160us  13.250us  reset_timesurface(__int64, __int64*, __int64*, __int64*, __int64*, float*, float*, bool*, bool*, Event*)
  7.36%  3.8239ms         8  477.99us  148.92us  620.17us  [CUDA memset]

==9258== API calls:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 53.12%  1.22036s      5005  243.83us  9.6670us  8.5762ms  cudaDeviceSynchronize
 25.10%  576.78ms      5005  115.24us  44.250us  11.888ms  cudaLaunch
  9.13%  209.77ms         9  23.308ms  16.667us  208.54ms  cudaMalloc
  6.56%  150.65ms         1  150.65ms  150.65ms  150.65ms  cudaDeviceReset
  5.33%  122.39ms     50050  2.4450us     833ns  6.1167ms  cudaSetupArgument
  0.60%  13.808ms      5005  2.7580us  1.0830us  104.25us  cudaConfigureCall
  0.10%  2.3845ms         9  264.94us  22.333us  537.75us  cudaFree
  0.04%  938.75us         8  117.34us  58.917us  169.08us  cudaMemset
  0.02%  461.33us        83  5.5580us  1.4160us  197.58us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
  0.00%  15.500us         2  7.7500us  3.6670us  11.833us  cuDeviceGetCount
  0.00%  7.6670us         1  7.6670us  7.6670us  7.6670us  cuDeviceTotalMem
  0.00%  4.8340us         1  4.8340us  4.8340us  4.8340us  cuDeviceGetName
  0.00%  3.6670us         2  1.8330us  1.6670us  2.0000us  cuDeviceGet
*/
```

Comment: Why do you need `cudaDeviceSynchronize`? I don't see such need in your procedure.

Comment: I am very skeptical of your timing. On a standard desktop linux system, nvprof tells me that cudaDeviceSynchronize following an empty kernel launch with 1 thread takes 4 microseconds. Can you provide a repro case and API trace for this behaviour ?

Comment: @kangshiyin At first I used `cudaDeviceSynchronize` because I hadn't stored my data yet. That's right, in the end I'll use `cudaMemcpy` instead; but does it really change anything, since `cudaMemcpy` implicitly synchronize? It should be even longer I suppose.

Comment: @talonmies Thanks for your reply; I updated the message with one `nvprof` log of the real app, and one repro case.

Comment: I tried running this code on a desktop GPU, and the average of the 5005 calls to `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` was ~7us, not 243.

Comment: I also can't reproduce anything like this using the provided code, I get a average of 4.3us for 5005 calls. Fundamentally, the call will only take longer if the device is busy. Perhaps on the platform you are running, either the GPU or driver cannot keep up with the volume of asynchronous operations your example code generates. On mine it clearly can

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks for trying the code. Well, I pasted the exact output of `nvprof`. I ran the code multiple times on a Jetson TK1; some outputs are lower than 243us, but nowhere near 7us. I'll try to compare with another board.

Comment: @talonmies The Tegra K1 should be able to manage a maximum of 2048 thread (or 16 blocks, or 64 warps) at the same time, and I'm just running 1. Yes, maybe something is using the device (even though I rebooted), I'll dig into it / try to use another GPU, thanks.

Comment: @Hyllis: it isn't anything to do with the thread or block capacity of the GPU. It is about the scheduling responsiveness of the device and driver to commands from the CUDA API. This is much more likely to be a question of latency

Comment: I think the issue here is that CUDA has a slightly different lazy initialization sequence on TK1 than it does on the desktop.  This means that the average of your 5005 calls to `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` is getting polluted by the first call being exceptionally long (8.57ms) which is polluting the average, whereas in my test the worst case was 16us, not 7us, so the average is not polluted - my CUDA startup overhead is being mostly absorbed in another call.  You can eliminate this effect with careful profiling, e.g. using the start/stop in the CUDA profiler API.

Comment: @talonmies I tried with a Jetson TX1, it's a bit less ridiculous: 45-90us in average instead of 120-250us. -- Thanks, so, is this only dependent of the device/hardware, or am I able to do something to make things quicker?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Nice thanks, I'll try to do better testings!

Comment: [here](http://pastebin.com/ptBzjdfF) is an example of what I had in mind.  Try something like that.  I bet you'll find the average for `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` is a lot lower.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Unfortunately, I hardly get any better result, both on the TK1 and the TX1. `862.65ms      5005  172.36us  9.7500us  11.094ms  cudaDeviceSynchronize`, the delta between min and max is still ridiculously high. I also tried doing more than one (60000...) warm-up before the `cudaProfilerStart`, but it doesn't change anything. -- Thanks both, now I have something to search for, I'll keep digging into latency and lazy initialization.

Comment: In that case then it would seem that TX1/TK1 have some statistical outliers that I can't explain.  Is your TK1 driving an X display?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Yes, it has Ubuntu 14.04 with lightdm. I just tried stopping the service; the measurements are still basically the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As detailled in the comments of the original message, my problem was entirely related to the GPU I'm using (Tegra K1). Here's an answer I found for this particular problem; it might be useful for other GPUs as well. The average for `cudaDeviceSynchronize` on my Jetson TK1 went from 250us to 10us.

The rate of the Tegra was 72000kHz by default, we'll have to set it to 852000kHz using this command:

```
$ echo 852000000 > /sys/kernel/debug/clock/override.gbus/rate
$ echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/clock/override.gbus/state
```

We can find the list of available frequency using this command:

```
$ cat /sys/kernel/debug/clock/gbus/possible_rates
72000 108000 180000 252000 324000 396000 468000 540000 612000 648000 684000 708000 756000 804000 852000 (kHz)
```

More performance can be obtained *(again, in exchange for a higher power draw)* on both the CPU and GPU; check [this link](http://elinux.org/Jetson/Performance) for more informations.